# I cannot get a key in gnupg - file not found

Tags: command-line, sudo, gnupg

In order to get a software working I need to get a key.
I tried it as a user, then as root, no effect.
Checked with Synaptic if all software for gnupg is there, do not see anything missing.
I build up the system new with Kubuntu 22.04.
Can someone give a hint please where to search for a solution?

```
root@BeQuiet-Lin:~# sudo gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/keyrings/ckvsoft-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 410EE8C739BB4452
gpg: failed to create temporary file '/root/.gnupg/.#lk0x0000564c33fcee80.BeQuiet-Lin.58324': No such file or directory
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/root/.gnupg/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked but there seems to be a problem with the public key which i have to ask ckvsoft.

Answer (score 0):

That error:

```
gpg: failed to create temporary file '/root/.gnupg/.#lk0x0000564c33fcee80.BeQuiet-Lin.58324': No such file or directory
gpg: connecting dirmngr at '/root/.gnupg/S.dirmngr' failed: No such file or directory
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No dirmngr
```

... is because `gpg` needs to create some temporary files under the defined configuration directory ... It's by default [`.gnupg`](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration.html) under the user's home directory which is present in the environment variable `HOME` and that in the case with `sudo` will resolve to `/root`.

But, the directory `/root/.gnupg` doesn't exist.

... So, you can either set the `HOME` variable to your current user's home directory on the command line with `HOME="$HOME"` like so:

```
sudo HOME="$HOME" gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/keyrings/ckvsoft-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 410EE8C739BB4452
```

... or use the `gpg`'s option `--homedir` to point to your user's current `"$HOME"` like so:

```
sudo gpg --homedir "$HOME" --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/keyrings/ckvsoft-archive-keyring.gpg --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 410EE8C739BB4452
```